# Add thousand separator for helpful flags count in user profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

The count of helpful flags on the user profile page doesn't use a thousand separator. There are other areas like that, I know, but this one stands out much more as it's right next to the profile views count which uses the separator.

[image]

I know this is small but I guess won't be hard to change.

Comment: `&thinsp;` is the one true thousands seperator! U+2009 2014.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now, as part of the general user profile overhaul.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen That's correct. Put that as an answer and I'll accept it to let everyone know it's done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've added a client-side fix for this issue into the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.10.  Alas, I have not been able to test it fully under "natural" conditions, since I don't actually have a four-digit helpful flag count on any SE site, but it does work as expected if I kluge it to artificially inflate the count.

In case you're curious, here's the code:

```javascript
var links = $('body.user-page #user-info-container a[href^="/users/flag-summary/"]');
SOUP.forEachTextNode( links, function () {
    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace( /[0-9]{4,}/g, function (digits) {
        return Number( digits ).toLocaleString( 'en-US' );
    } );
} );
```

Note that, since the fix is based on `Number.toLocaleString()`, some older browsers might format the number according to the user's selected locale.  All officially [supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) should respect the explicit `en-US` locale I'm specifying, though.

**Edit:** It seems the original fix caused some minor formatting breakage for moderators.  SOUP v1.10.2 uses the updated code above, which should be more tolerant of the link(s) containing more than just a simple number.  Thanks to Monica Cellio for reporting this issue!

**Update:** As of mid-2015, it seems that this issue has been quietly fixed at some point, presumably as part of the general user profile overhaul carried out in spring.  The client-side hack described above will thus be retired from the next release of SOUP.